# Simple voting system without a gem - how to track up or down vote and allow one vote per user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

Any help would be most appreciated. I am less three weeks into my rails journey, thus apologies in advance.

I've written a simple list voting system, a user can up or down vote said list. It works okay. However, I am stuck on two issues:

1. What is the most efficient way of restricting a user_id to vote once? However, they can then toggle their vote up or down. I began over-engineering a `after_touch` Callback. Is the best practice to set a has_one :vote in the User model? Does Active Record take care of everything after that?
2. Is it possible to disable the vote (up or down) button when a user clicked the button. Without adding another database column to track a up or down vote? So they can toggle between up or down voting, after the initial vote cast.

Votes Controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
    def vote_up
        @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
        @vote = Vote.find_or_create_by(list_id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
        Vote.increment_counter(:vote_count, @vote)
        redirect_to list_path(@list), notice: 'Voted Up.'
    end

    def vote_down
        @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
        @vote = Vote.find_or_create_by(list_id: params[:id], user_id: current_user.id)
        Vote.decrement_counter(:vote_count, @vote)
        redirect_to list_path(@list), notice: 'Voted Down.'    
    end
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "vote_count"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "list_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["list_id"], name: "index_votes_on_list_id"
  end
```

excerpt of show.html.erb with relevant up/down vote buttons

```
<% if @list.votes.any? %>
  Count Of Votes <%= content_tag(:p, list_vote_counter?) %>
<% end %>
<%= button_to 'Vote Up', list_vote_up_path, method: :post, params: { list_id: params[:id] } %>
<%= button_to 'Vote Down', list_vote_down_path, method: :post, params: { list_id: params[:id] } %>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing. You say you want to set `User` to `has_one :vote`. But your table seems to be a join table for `user_id` and `list_id`. So a person could have ONE vote PER LIST, correct? You can enforce uniqueness but not the way you mentioned.

You don't have your model code for all of the models, but you could make a List model have

```
has_many :votes
has_many :users, through: :votes
```

Then Users has

```
has_many :votes
has_many :lists, through: votes
```

and the Votes model can have

```
belongs_to: :user
belongs_to: :list
validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :list_id }
```

That last uniqueness validation would prevent more than one user vote per list from what I understand here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: many thanks for your response & taking time out of your day to help me. I apologise, I should have listed my models. Regrettably, your above generates a SystemStackError (stack level too deep) error, as my models are not listed out. For now I've stuck a band aid on top of my code. With an application controller helper method ```    def user_voted_on_list?
        @check = List.find(params[:id]).votes.where(user_id: @user).present?
    end``` and hide/reveal the buttons accordingly, until I have enough working knowledge to revisit your answer with better knowledge.